# how to make dango url ignore query string in urls.py

Tags: python, django, hyperlink

I'm working on a website where I can have the user choose from a list of similar elements on a list page and I want it to open a separate page based on the element they choose in the list

I have a list setup and each element in the list is identifiable with a random string of 15 characters containing `[0-9]`, `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`.

Example of an url for an element of the list: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/view?s=fkiscl49gtisceg`

where `s` is the identifier (kinda like how youtube videos have a seperate link)

however I can't understand how I need to make django ignore the `?s=fkiscl49gtisceg` part of the string. I've written the path like this now:

```
path('view/(?P<s>[\w]{15})', element_display, name='s'),
```

django however tels me that the page was not found... How do I fix this?

Comment: Django **always** ignores the query string in urls.py.

Comment: then why does it tell me the page was not found whenever I try it?

Comment: Because you've confused `path()` with `url()`. `path()` doesn't take regular expressions.

Comment: allright i'll try changing it to url

Comment: However in your update what is the `v` parameter? You only have one element in that URL, "view".

Comment: v should be s (they are the same in my code i just had a little mind error copying it over as I am writing this on my phone)

Comment: it should be right now!

Comment: But hang on, you just said you want it to *ignore* the querystring. Which is it?

Comment: i want it to always go to view no matter what the querysting is or if it is there at all.

Comment: you have an error in url definition. view/(?P<s>[\w]{15}) this pattern won't match view?s=fkiscl49gtisceg, because as you've written you must have "/" after view and "?" is not in your pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle is simply that Django **does not take any account of the querystring**. Therefore, you should not have it in your pattern. The URL should just be `path('view')`.